# Install conda-forge mlxtend - Error in installing mlxtend - Permission Denied

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install mlxtend from terminal by using following command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge mlxtend
```

everything was working well until I got this following error:

```
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan ##

environment location: /home/uay/anaconda3

added / updated specs: 
  - mlxtend


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

   mlxtend: 0.13.0-py_1  conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda:   4.5.4-py36_0 conda-forge --> 4.5.8-py36_1 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'conda-forge::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Attempting to roll back.
    Rolling back transaction: done
    PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

I am using Linux Mint. Anyone had this kind of issue, kindly suggest. Thank you.  Sudo command Not woking here.

Comment: What are the permissions for the content of `/home/uay/anaconda3`? Everything owned and read and writable for your user?

Comment: owner for anaconda3 is root, not current user.

Comment: if I am opening terminal as root, and using the terminal, then I am getting "Command Not Found"

Comment: change it to current user then. Also, you are getting the command not found, because conda is most likely only added to the PATH in the .bashrc of the user `uay`

Comment: I have changed anaconda3 to current user, and after that I am able to install mlxtend on conda; thanks for that, and now my .bashrc has path as: export PATH=/home/uay/anaconda3/bin:$PATH, is it ok, or do I need any change. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an older version of this command.

> conda install -c rasbt mlxtend

Change your permission for anaconda to current user. Hope it'll work.